# Unable to add images to javascript as a table

Tags: javascript, html, image, javascript-objects

I have a js file where I have created a table that adjusts dynamically, and I have figured out how to add text to the columns. I also wanted to add images that I can access from an array and show them as a column also. I've tried a couple of things and I just get [object HTMLImageElement].

Here is my code:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= testNum; i++) {
      cInstance.tests(i).then(function(test) {
      var id = test[0];
      var name = test[1];
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = images[i];

      var testTemplate = "<tr><th>" + img + "</th><td>" + name + "</td></tr>"
      testResults.append(testTemplate);

      var testOption = "<option value='" + id + "' >" + name + "</ option>"
      testsSelect.append(testOption);


    });
```

I have images array initialized outside the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An image is an HTML DOM element, if you add it to your template, it will be converted to a string (so you get a string: [object HTMLImageElement]). You should add it to another DOM element with appendChild() ...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you give a quick example of the implementation, how I could do it?

Comment: `let testTemplate = "<tr><th><img src=" + images[i] + "></th><td>" + name + "</td></tr>";`